# How to send first value of an array to sendmessage method in php telegram bot?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I want to get the message from user in the telegram bot and return some part of their text as a reply which specified by regular expression:

`preg_match('/\b(?:[a-z]+\d|\d+[a-z])[a-z\d]*\b/i', $text, $matches); 
message($chat_id,$matches,$message_id);` -> shows Array `message($chat_id,$matches[0],$message_id);` -> shows nothing

And message function is:

```
function bot($data)
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org  /bot".API_TOKEN."/".$data),true);
}

function message($chat_id,$msg,$msg_id)
{
    bot("sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$msg."&reply_to_message_id=".$msg_id);
}
```

and

```
$chat_id=$update['message']['chat']['id'];
$message_id=$update['message']['message_id'];
$text=$update['message']['text'];
```

EDIT:

I changed the code to `message($chat_id,v$matches[0][0],$message_id)` and it returns only the first character of the word (For example instead of `ac64fc`, it returns just letter `a` ) 
`message($chat_id,$matches[0][0].$matches[0][1],$message_id)`=ac in the example above

Comment: So what does `$matches` actually contain then, have you checked that?

Comment: in the php it contains the text which have both digit and alphabet, like :
`<?php

$subject = "foo ac64fc bar 4544";
preg_match('/\b(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\b/i', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // ac64fc

`
but in the telegram bot , the only way of printing variables is sending them to sendmessage method, and sendmessage method only shows 'Array'

Comment: What happens when you try `message($chat_id,$matches[0],$message_id)` ? I just tried it with this string: "foo ac64fc bar 4544" and  it worked just fine